# Why is the mean distance from a member in a set to other members in the set not equal to the mean absolute deviation?

Tags: statistics, average, means

Given mean absolute distance as $MAD=\sum{\frac{|x_i-\bar{x}|}{n}}$ where $x_i$ is the $i$th term and $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean and considering a set $M=\lbrace 3,4,5 \rbrace$, when we consider each of $\frac{\frac{|3-3|+|3-4|+|3-5|}{3} + \frac{|4-4|+|4-3|+|4-5|}{3} +\frac{|5-5|+|5-4|+|5-3|}{3}}{3}$ why is this not equal to $\frac{|3-4|+|4-4|+|5-4|}{3}$?

As a clarification, I was considering the concept intuitively, for standard deviation, and was assuming my impression would coincide with what was established regarding deviation from the mean. I am having difficulty seeing why these two measures fail to line up and hoping to find something along the lines of "That measure is referred to as..." and perhaps an accompanying explanation for their divergence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Already for 2 elements they are not the same. MAD is half the distance between the 2 elements, the "avarage" distance is just that distance. So your intuition is simply ill-guided, it seems.

Comment: While not an active member, I will take a stand as an educator and say that I would not say "your intuition is simply ill-guided". As a community, we should seek to encourage the asking of questions and be supportive of one another. How is it an ill-guided perception to see that if something is true with regard to the mean it might also be true regarding those things that compose the mean? Instead, you could write, 'I see you're trying to connect between the mean and what might compose the mean, but in this instance, what you claim composes the mean does not.'

Comment: Also, 'I am not aware of any formal descriptions. That might be interesting to pursue further.'

Comment: Moreso, I'd like to know what that measure is, and as it is so simple a measure, I figured it likely has a name and that there would be more information available on it.

Comment: @neurosciencecalc It wasn't meant as a discouragement, it was meant that your initial idea was easily seen to be not correct for a very simple case. There are connections between the two values, just not as conjectured. I don't see a material difference between the meanings of my sentence and yours, you had an intuition, and it was wrong. That is not bad, but I wanted to make that clear, and that is was (to me) relatively easy to find an even simpler examples that what you provided. As I said, you inituition was in this case guided into the wrong direction, which is "ill-guided".